# How to retrieve files inside folder in document library using javascript

Tags: javascript, document-library, sharepoint-addin

I need the code to retrieve files from folders in document library

Answer (score 3):

An example of how to Get Files from a Folder using Ecmascript\Javascript client object model in SharePoint 2010

```
<script type=”text/ecmascript”>
function ViewAllFiles()
{
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(‘Shared Documents’);
var query = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
query.set_folderServerRelativeUrl(‘/Shared%20Documents/TestFolder’);
allItems = list.getItems(query);
context.load(allItems, ‘Include(Title, ContentType, File)’);
context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.success),   Function.createDelegate(this, this.failed));
}

function success()
{
  var fileUrls = “”;
  var ListEnumerator = this.allItems.getEnumerator();
   while(ListEnumerator.moveNext())
   {
    var currentItem = ListEnumerator.get_current();
    var _contentType = currentItem.get_contentType();
     if(_contentType.get_name() != “Folder”)
       {
        var File = currentItem.get_file();
        if(File != null)
          {
           fileUrls += File.get_serverRelativeUrl() + ‘\n';
          }
       }
   }
  alert(fileUrls);
 }
 function failed(sender, args) {
  alert(“failed. Message:” + args.get_message());
 }
 </script>
 <a href=”#” onclick=”Javascript:ViewAllFiles();”>View All Files in Test Folder</a>
```

Please replace Document Library name and folder as per your requirement.

Comment: I am creating folder dynamically,then what changes i need to make.

Comment: if you are creating folders dynamically then in that case you will have to get folder Name and relace the folder name in  set_folderServerRelativeUrl() method.

Comment: you can also follow below article by Nadeem http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/ in this you don't need to pass folder name.  Use createAllItemsQuery to get items inside subfolders as well. Otherwise use new SP.CamlQuery() to get items from a single folder only.

Comment: Here is link to the post: http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2014/11/sharepoint-get-files-from-folder-using.html

Comment: context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.success),   Function.createDelegate(this, this.failed));.This statement is giving me an error saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'OnSuccess' of undefined".How will i resolve this?

Comment: how to download the multiple files on a button click using JSOM,  ECMA script. by default, http doesnt allow multiple downloading of files from the browser. then , how to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution

```
var hostweburl;
var appweburl;
var allItems;
//Load the required SharePoint libraries.
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Get the URI decoded URLs.
    hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(
getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
    appweburl = decodeURIComponent(
getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl"));

    GetFolders();
});
function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
    var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
    for(var i = 0; i< params.length; i = i + 1) {
        var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
        if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve) return singleParam[1];
    }
}
function GetFolders() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(appweburl);
    var appCtxSite = new SP.AppContextSite(clientContext, hostweburl);
    var web = appCtxSite.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('TPSDocument');
    var query = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
    // query.set_folderServerRelativeUrl('/TPSDocuments/TestFolders');
    allItems = list.getItems(query);
    clientContext.load(allItems, 'Include(Title, ContentType, File)');
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(success, failed);
}
function success() {
    alert("success");
    var fileUrls = "";
    var Filename = new Array();
    var i = 0;
    var ListEnumerator = allItems.getEnumerator();
    while (ListEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var currentItem = ListEnumerator.get_current();
        var _contentType = currentItem.get_contentType();
        if (_contentType.get_name() != "Folder") {
            var File = currentItem.get_file();
            if (File != null) {
                fileUrls += File.get_serverRelativeUrl() + '\n';
                var url = fileUrls.split('/');
                var folder = url[url.length - 2];
                if (folder == "TestFolder") {
                    Filename[i] = File.get_name();
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    alert(Filename);
    alert(fileUrls);
}
function failed(sender, args) {
    alert("failed. Message:" + args.get_message());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***How to retrieve all the images inside a folder from a document lib using JSOM***

```
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js "></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    $(document).ready( function () { 
            ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(GetFilesFromFolder, "sp.js");
            });
var allItems;
function GetFilesFromFolder(listTitle, folderServerRelativeUrl)
{
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('libraryname');
    // Use createAllItemsQuery to get items inside subfolders as well. Otherwise use new SP.CamlQuery() to get items from a single folder only
    var query = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
    query.set_folderServerRelativeUrl('libraryname/foldernmae');
    allItems = list.getItems(query);
    context.load(allItems, 'Include(File, FileSystemObjectType)');
    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnFailure));
}
function OnSuccess()
{
 pictureArray = new Array();
 var pictureCount = 0;  
 var txtHTML = "";
    var listItemEnumerator = allItems.getEnumerator();
    while(listItemEnumerator.moveNext())
    {
        var currentItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();                                                                                                                     

            var file = currentItem.get_file();
            var path = file.get_serverRelativeUrl();
            pictureArray[pictureCount++] = path;
            }
            if(file != null)
            {
                var row = document.createElement("tr");
                    var j = 0;
                    for(i=0; i<this.pictureArray.length; i++) 
                    {
                    if (j == 0)
                    txtHTML += "<tr>";
                    txtHTML += "<td>";                       
                     txtHTML += "<a href='"+ this.pictureArray[i] +"'><image border='none' src='" + this.pictureArray[i] + "'></Image></a>"                              
                     txtHTML +="</td>";
                     j++;
                     if (j == 2)
                     {
                     txtHTML += "</tr>";
                     j = 0;
                     }
                    }




            }
        $("#tblCustomListData").append(txtHTML);

}

function OnFailure(sender, args) {
    alert("Failed. Message:" + args.get_message());
}
```