# How can I get a subfolder's GUID which is under a document library with soap and javascript or CAML query?

Tags: javascript, document-library, caml-query, soap

[image]

I want to fetch this subfolder's documents. but CAML is not showing the documents clearly . thak you.

Answer (score 2):

I have found similar question on the same requirements.

Please check the below links:

1. [How to retrieve files inside folder in document library using javascript](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/127743/how-to-retrieve-files-inside-folder-in-document-library-using-javascript)
2. [SharePoint: Get Files from folder using JavaScript client object model](http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2014/11/sharepoint-get-files-from-folder-using.html?m=1)

Also there is a very helpful article related to working with folders and files in SharePoint by Microsoft. Check the article using below link:

[Working with folders and files with REST](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-REST).